# Passing by reference [C++], [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote something like this:

```
class Storage
{
public:
    Storage();
    QString key() const;
    int value() const;
    void add_item(QString&,int);
private:
    QMap<QString,int>* my_map_;
};

void Storage::add_item(QString& key,int value)//------HERE IS THE SLOT FOR ADDING
{
   *my_map_[key] = value;
}
```

and when I'm trying to add item to `QMap` by:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Dialog(QWidget* = 0);
public slots:
    void add_item()
    {
        strg_->add_item(ui->lineEdit->text(),ui->spinBox->value());//---HERE I'M "PASSING" TWO OBJECTS: QString AND int
        ui->lineEdit->clear();
    }

private:
    Ui::Dialog* ui;
    Storage* strg_;
};
```

I'm getting error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Storage::add_item(QString, int)
note: candidates are: void Storage::add_item(QString&, int)
```

How am I suppose to send `QString` by ref. other then I do it now?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add_item should take a "const QString&" rather than a "QString&" as parameter.

Comment: @Rudy: Because there's no reason `add_item` would want to modify a `QString` object.

Answer (score 2):

This line returns a QString by **value**

```
ui->lineEdit->text(),ui->spinBox->value()
```

Hence, you can't use it as a modifiable reference. However, you can use it as a non-modifiable (const) reference, by modifying the function add_item to take `const QString&`.

```
void Storage::add_item(const QString& key,int value)
{
   *my_map_[key] = value;
}
```

Also, depending on the implementation of QString, it might be as effective to just pass it by value:

```
void Storage::add_item(QString key,int value)
{
   *my_map_[key] = value;
}
```

... note however, that usually with classes it's a lot more effective to use const references where possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ui->lineEdit->text()` appears to return a `QString` and not a `QString&`.

You cannot pass this by reference to the `add_item` function because it does not exist anywhere, it's just a temporary copy returned by that function.  if you declare it on the stack and then pass it like below, it should work:

```
QString qs = ui->lineEdit->text();
strg_->add_item(qs,ui->spinBox->value());
```

Comment: It can be passed by const-reference instead.

Comment: @Joe, yes, and it only works around the issue, instead of solving it.