# passing reference in C++ using const var&

Tags: c++

I have a problem that similar to : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048664/passing-by-reference-c-qt)

But I still don't understand what is the difference between  :

```
void test(TestInfo&)
{

}
```

and

```
void test(const TestInfo&)
{

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first passes a reference while the second passes an `const` reference to the function `test()`,
Note that `const` reference basically means a reference to a `const` data.

In the second case you cannot modify the contents of `TestInfo` inside the function.
Any attempt to modify the passed `TestInfo` object inside the function would result in a
**Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: oh my. I remembered now. 10 years never touched C++ resulting in this stupid question. :)

Comment: "Any attempt to modify the passed TestInfo object inside the function would result in Undefined Behaviour" - luckily, most meer accidental attempts result in compilation errors, whereas undefined behaviour is a run-time problem.  Even actual modification - say after deliberately casting away `const` with `const_cast<>` or a C-style cast, has defined behaviour unless the `TestInfo` instance happened to be a static/global/namespace level `const` (compiler prevents caller from accidentally passing anyway), or cases where `test(TestInfo&)` would also fail due to thread (un)safety etc...

Comment: @TonyDelroy: *Even actual modification - say after deliberately casting away const with `const_cast<>` or a C-style cast, has defined behaviour unless the `TestInfo` instance happened to be a static/global/namespace level const* What is the *defined behavior* if the argument passed is a local constant and the function modifies it?

Comment: @Als: ahhh... my list of exclusions missed that case too, but have you understated them? - if the caller has `TestInfo x; f(x); // use x more`, calling `f(const TestInfo& x) { const_cast<TestInfo&>(x) = 10; }`, is the behaviour not defined?  In compiling the calling code, the optimiser generally can't assume that `x` won't be modified by `f()` - ties back in to that old FAQ "does `const` help the optimiser generate more efficient code? - no".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Als said, the significant of the 2nd is that even though the variable is passed by reference it functions similar to as if passing by value. This can be useful if you are passing a large object. Passing an object by value creates a new object on stack but passing by reference doesn't. When you do `const TesetInfo&`the new variable will not be created but it will essentially function as if it is passed by value. This will be slightly efficient approach.

Comment: +1 Great point.  Also important for objects that just can't be copied, or shouldn't be as they represent resources for which copying is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not being able to modify the argument passed in, if TestInfo is a class for example, you'll get compile errors if you try and call non const member functions on it ( Const member functions are functions that promise not to modify the object).

Here are a couple of good reads on const:

1. [Const tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html)
2. [Const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)